# PHP Instagram API - Getting all images for a tag. How to create a pagination with min and max_tag_id

Tags: php, pagination, instagram

I'm working around the Instagram PHP API to get all images/posts for a specific tag in Instagram.

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
 function callInstagram($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }

    $tag = "bulgaria";
    $client_id = "1e0f576fbdb44e299924a93cace24507";
    $Next_URL = $_GET["nexturl"];
    if($Next_URL == ""){
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id.'&count=24';
    } else {
    $url =  $Next_URL;
    }
    $inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
    $results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);
    $maxid = $results['pagination']['next_max_id'];
    $nexturl = $results['pagination']['next_url'];
    //Now parse through the $results array to display your results... 
    foreach($results['data'] as $item){
        $image_link = $item['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
        $Profile_name = $item['user']['username'];
        
        echo '<div style="display:block;float:left;">'.$Profile_name.' <br> <img src="'.$image_link.'" /></div>';
    }
    
    echo "<div style='display:block;width:100%;clear:both;'>MaxID: $maxid <br>NextURL: <a href='?nexturl=$nexturl'>Next images</a> <br>N: $Next_URL</div>";
```

With this code it seems I'm able to get some images but I can not display the next ones when I click on `Next images`.

I am trying to create some kind of pagination with the `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` given here: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

But I seems these two `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` are not working for me, but why?

Answer (score 0):

**As of Nov 2017**, Instagram has just changed their policy again and does [not allow people to apply for permissions for public content anymore](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/).

The change may haven been made because Instagram plans to [allow users to follow hashtags on IG itself](https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/10/instagram-could-let-you-follow-hashtags-soon/). They don't want any (new) third party having a similar feature that they could make money from.